# C++ How to access the dynamical objects attributes

Tags: c++, object

in my code, i've got two different objects. One "normal" object and one dynamical object:

1.)

```
Person firstPerson("Bernd",22);
```

2.)

```
Person* secondPerson = new Person("Andria", 33);
```

Now i want to create a method that can print the objects values (Name, Age) on the console. The Method below is working for the first object(1.) but not for the second object (2.):

```
void Person::printData(){
    std::cout << "Name: " << Person::getName() << " ; Age: " << Person::getAge() << "." << std::endl;
}
```

How do i access the attributes of a dynamical created object? I know that i have to use "->" but i dont know how. 
And is there a way to create only one method that is working for both methods?
Like:

```
firstPerson.printData();
secondPerson.printData();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So why can't you do secondPerson->printData()?

Comment: Not sure why but i didnt think about that solution, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `secondPerson` is a pointer do this: `secondPerson->printData();`